Trouble Importing Videos in remLogic Project
I'm encountering an issue while importing videos recorded with Netstation into a project using the remLogic library.
I've searched for solutions online but can't find a solution to this problem.
When importing the video, I get the message "rendering" (which lasts forever).
Has anyone encountered and solved it?
Things I tried:

Changing the video properties (codec, resolution, bit rate etc)
I also tried to add video tags I saw the remLogic videos have ('ESVS','ESVB','ESVE') but can't find how to do that
Checked manual, nothing specific there.

Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
